# All these taxes tags are taxing

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There's [tax](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tax), [taxation](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taxation), and [taxes](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taxes).

I don't see how these are any different? They should be merged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tags were merged by Yannis; thanks!

(Adding an answer, otherwise the Community user will keep bumping this to the top in a while since it's an upvoted question with no answer, [even if it has status-completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11576/166789)).